# Does a template for a system architecture/design proposal exist?

Tags: documentation

I need to prepare a proposal for the technical specification in the development of a new project, what I've done before was to include the following:

- **Platform** The primary technology and secondary ones the system will be programmed
- **OS Target** The target in which the system will run
- **Application Server** in the case of a web application
- **Application Modules** The main modules or tiers the application will be composed.
- **Architecture overview** Some brief explanation talking about how the modules will interact together inside the application
- **Interactions** How the system will interact with other systems

Besides this sometimes it's worth to specify some things like:

- **SCM** If I'm using CVS, SVN, git
- **Database** Sometimes I found necessary to list the reasons for using an specific RDBMS

I know I might be totally wrong (that's why I'm asking this here) so I was wondering. Does a template for architecture specification exist? If not -which is the most probable-, what things do you recommend to include in that document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use parts of the Rational Unified Process (RUP) for documentation template. You can refer to this question for a number of Open Source alternatives: [Rational Unified Process Alternative for Documentation and Templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337708/rational-unified-process-alternative-for-documentation-and-templates)